# How should I use tooltip-speed properly?

Tags: angularjs, tooltip

I'm trying to set transition speed of [**720kb/angular-tooltips**] tooltips show/hide to 0.5sec.
Default speed in "slow" mode is 0.65sec(from default css), and that's ok for me - I can use this instead of 0.5sec.

But after set mode to **slow**, nothing really changes.

```
 <a href='#' tooltips tooltip-template="{{n.FileName}}" tooltip-speed="slow"> {{n.FileName}} </a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u898mg2m/17/

above is test of using tooltip-speed attribute

Alternative question: is there another way to delay tool-tips (show and/or hide)?

Comment: why you dont just edit the css file with 0.5 secs?

Comment: This doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/720kb/angular-tooltips/blob/master/lib/angular-tooltips.scss You can change the values in the following .scss as you can see or define your own new transition variable.

You can set 0 for fast 1 for slow and 0.5 for steady variables.
Now to get the delay you need to change the opacity variables depending upon your requirements. Set the percentages according to the delay.Allow for smaller opacity to get a smooth transition.

Here is a fiddle for you  http://jsfiddle.net/u898mg2m/21/

```
/*
 * angular-tooltips
 * 1.1.1
 * 
 * Angular.js tooltips module.
 * http://720kb.github.io/angular-tooltips
 * 
 * MIT license
 * Wed May 18 2016
 */
tooltip._bottom tip tip-arrow,tooltip._top tip tip-arrow{border-left:6px solid transparent;border-right:6px solid transparent;left:50%;margin-left:-6px}._exradicated-tooltip{position:absolute;display:block;opacity:1;z-index:999}tooltip{display:inline-block;position:relative}@-webkit-keyframes animate-tooltip{0%{opacity:0}50%{opacity:0}60%{opacity:0}70%{opacity:0}90%{opacity:0}}@-moz-keyframes animate-tooltip{0%{opacity:0}50%{opacity:0}60%{opacity:0}70%{opacity:0}90%{opacity:1}}@-ms-keyframes animate-tooltip{tooltip 0%{opacity:0}tooltip 50%{opacity:.5}tooltip 60%{opacity:.8}tooltip 70%{opacity:.9}tooltip 90%{opacity:1}}@keyframes animate-tooltip{0%{opacity:0}50%{opacity:0}60%{opacity:0}70%{opacity:0}90%{opacity:1}}tooltip._multiline{display:block}tooltip._slow._ready tip{animation:animate-tooltip 1s}tooltip._fast._ready tip{animation:animate-tooltip 0s}tooltip._steady._ready tip{animation:animate-tooltip .5s}tooltip tip{border-radius:3px;background:rgba(0,0,0,.85);color:#fff;display:none;line-height:normal;max-width:500px;min-width:100px;opacity:0;padding:8px 16px;position:absolute;text-align:center;width:auto;will-change:top,left,bottom,right}tooltip tip._hidden{display:block;visibility:hidden}tooltip.active:not(._force-hidden) tip{display:block;opacity:1;z-index:999}tooltip tip-tip{font-size:.95em}tooltip tip-tip._large{font-size:1.1em}tooltip tip-tip._small{font-size:.8em}tooltip._top tip{left:50%;top:-9px;-webkit-transform:translateX(-50%) translateY(-100%);transform:translateX(-50%) translateY(-100%)}tooltip._top tip tip-arrow{border-top:6px solid rgba(0,0,0,.85);content:'';height:0;position:absolute;top:100%;width:0}tooltip._bottom tip{right:50%;top:100%;-webkit-transform:translateX(50%) translateY(9px);transform:translateX(50%) translateY(9px)}tooltip._bottom tip tip-arrow{border-bottom:6px solid rgba(0,0,0,.85);bottom:100%;content:'';height:0;position:absolute;width:0}tooltip._left tip tip-arrow,tooltip._right tip tip-arrow{border-bottom:6px solid transparent;border-top:6px solid transparent;content:'';height:0;margin-top:-6px;position:absolute;top:50%;width:0}tooltip._right tip{left:100%;top:50%;-webkit-transform:translateX(9px) translateY(-50%);transform:translateX(9px) translateY(-50%)}tooltip._right tip tip-arrow{border-right:6px solid rgba(0,0,0,.85);right:100%}tooltip._left tip{left:-9px;top:50%;-webkit-transform:translateX(-100%) translateY(-50%);transform:translateX(-100%) translateY(-50%)}tooltip._left tip tip-arrow{border-left:6px solid rgba(0,0,0,.85);left:100%}tip-tip #close-button{cursor:pointer;float:right;left:8%;margin-top:-7%;padding:3px;position:relative}
/*# sourceMappingURL=angular-tooltips.css.map */


#link {
  padding:200px;
}
```

Hope it may help you.

Comment: set the time and the opacity according to your requirement. "opacity% == per sec transition"

Comment: Thx for your help. I see that your answer is correct, but in my case I have to change `animation` to `-webkit-animation`. 'animation' was an 'Unknown property name'